# Flask-admin and prepopulated value

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have small issue: simple class

```
class AModel(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(....)
  title = db.Column(....)
  uniq_text_id = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True. nullable=False)

def __init__(self):
  uniq_text_id = uuid4().hex
```

Now i adjusted flask-admin package and what administrator be able to create `AModel` instances. But there is 1 case: field `uniq_text_id` must be created automatically.

So, right now I cannot create mode because flask-admin says that fiel uniq_text_id in required, but also does not shows prepopulated value.

Is there any way to use prepopulated value in flask-admin forms or avoid somehow this problem without dropping `nullable=False` constraint?

**UPD:** @codegeek provided good solution for auto generated fields which still shown on the form. My own solution uses provided by flask-admin functionality allows to explicitly declares which columns are shown and which - hidden.

Answer (score 6):

You need to override the ModelView class for your model. Something like:

```
class AModelAdmin(sqlamodel.ModelView):

    uuidtext = uuid4()
    form_args = dict(
                uniq_text_id=dict(default=uuidtext)
            )

    def __init__(self, session):
        super(AModelAdmin, self).__init__(AModel, session)
```

Then you just need to add this to your admin

```
admin.add_view(AModelAdmin(db.session))
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault - read documentation too briefly. Created my model view like fillowing:

```
class MyUserLessonModelView(MyModelView):
    form_excluded_columns = ('uniq_text_id', 'created_by', 'created_date', 'modified_by', 'modified_date')
```

And all autogenerated fields are disappeared from form.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?